# I just saw this sentence on the internet

Tags: grammar

there is a sentence below..

> "no politician in history, and I say with surety, has been treated worse, more unfairly."

I don't understand this sentence grammatically

no politician and I together are the subject with plural form

so has must be changed to have.. IMO

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks the source, it lacks context, and the subject is evidently singular, remove the parenthetical phrase (and I...) and we're left with  "no politician **has** been treated more unfairly”

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is

> "no politician in history has been treated worse, more unfairly."

**no politician** is the subject

> and I say with surety

is a subordinate clause emphasizing that the speaker is sure of the fact they are stating, and no one is more sure of themself than **The Donald**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the context, but if this is the quote, it is not at all grammatically correct.  Instead, it is very colloquial.

My guess is that this was written about a politician.  Perhaps Mr. Trump?

The person quoted is basically stating that that the politician, in the opinion of the speaker ("and I say with surety") has been treated very poorly  and unfairly.

Try not to take these types of quotes too literally.   This quote, in particular, is not at all proper English.

Comment: For context, this is a quote said *by* Trump.